# MSI B450-A PRO BIOS Update Issue (Please Help, This is infuriating )

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, flashing

I recently completed a PC Build involving the aforementioned Motherboard. I booted into the BIOS and found that my BIOS version was not current.

After Attempting to flash a Bios update (Downloaded from [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B450-A-PRO), Version :7B86vA7) my MotherBoard crashed with the progress bar at 47% and will not reboot
Despite I checking and rechecking prior to flashing BIOS if the version I had downloaded was compatible.

where in this process did I go wrong?

Is the motherboard recoverable?

P.S Not sure if it's relevant but I ran the board with an AMD Athlon 200GE CPU

Comment: “where in this process did I go wrong?” - Nowhere;  Doesn’t change the fact that the system crashed while the firmware was being updated;  The only way you will be able to recovery from this without a warranty claim is if the motherboard has a backup firmware (check the motherboard manual to determine if that’s the case)

Comment: Try using the reset CMOS jumper. Page 37 for [v1.1 manual](https://www.scribd.com/document/404349272/E7A59v1-1). Page 36 for [v2.0 manual](https://www.scribd.com/document/404349273/E7B86v2-0)

Answer (score 0):

The mainboard supports BIOS flashback. Put the bios file into a FAT32 USB stick and plug in to a USB. After that press the flashback button which you'll find it on the I/O panel. 
You can read more about this procedure on the internet.